# Delete first line from a file and Update

Tags: shell, script

Here is the file i work on "list":

```
g-8.xx.yyy.zzzz
g-9.xx.yyy.zzzz
g-10.xx.yyy.zzzz
g-11.xx.yyy.zzzz
g-12.xx.yyy.zzzz
```

Here is the script i try to complete ( i'd like to get the first line and delete it from the file)

```
#! /bin/sh
nodes="list"
node=$(cat "$nodes")
```

Please, how can i delete the first line and update my file ?

"list" file will have this content

```
g-9.xx.yyy.zzzz
g-10.xx.yyy.zzzz
g-11.xx.yyy.zzzz
g-12.xx.yyy.zzzz
```

Thanks a lot for help.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash
node=$(sed -n 1p list)
sed -i 1d list
```

Comment: ok, i will test it :) Thanks a lot for help. Please, i'd like to get this line in a variable befor deleting it, how can i d that please ? Kind Regards.

Comment: @researcher I added a line to my answer.